# How to read BigQuery nested tables using Dataflow Python SDK

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

How can I read nested structures using Apache Beam Python SDK?

```
lines = p | io.Read(io.BigQuerySource('project:test.beam_in'))
```

result in

```
"reason": "invalidQuery",
"message": "Cannot output multiple independently repeated fields at the same time. Found classification_item_distribution and category_cat_name"
```

Is it possible to read nested structures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a property of BigQuery. The two ways to execute such a query are to disable result flattening (by BigQuery) or to explicitly flatten fields in your query.

With the current Python SDK only the latter is available - see "[Flattening Google Analytics data (with repeated fields) not working anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583878/flattening-google-analytics-data-with-repeated-fields-not-working-anymore)" for a guide on where and how to invoke the `FLATTEN` function.

The feature to disable flattening is filed as [BEAM-877](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-877) if you care to subscribe to updates or discuss.

Comment: Thank you. Interestingly enough, Java SDK allows nested structures without any extra configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can now read nested results directly in Beam Python by adding `flatten_results=False` when creating your source:

```
lines = p | io.Read(io.BigQuerySource('project:test.beam_in', flatten_results=False))
```

See source [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/0.6.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.html#BigQuerySource).